# How create radio button with dynamic value for images?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, kartik-v

I want to flag a image with radio button and send it inside the form, i need the value of this button Be the name of that image, my code in view is:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [

    'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*', 'id'=>'inputFile'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        layoutTemplates' => [
            'footer' => "<div class=\'file-thumbnail-footer\'>\n" .
  "    <div class='file-caption-name' style='width:{width}'>{caption}
  </div>\n" .
  {progress} {actions}" .
  '<div><br>
  <div class="radio-btn">

  <input type="radio" "id="rc1" name="rc1" checked="checked">

  <label for="rc1"><span class="label label-default" style="font-size: 
 1em;">Main image</span></label>

 </div></div>'.
 "</div>"
 ],
'uploadUrl' => '/ads/create',
'previewCaption' => false,
'fileActionSettings'=>['showZoom'=>false, 'showUpload'=>false],
                                       'previewFileType' => 'image',
                                       'maxFileCount' => 4,

        ]
    ]);
    ?>
```

How do I do this? i want this: **value='{image name}'**

Comment: is your code in the question a direct copy and paste? because you have some missing and/or extra and/or incorrectly nested single and double quotes which could be causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my anwer, i expected someone to help but no one could!!!

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [

    'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*', 'id'=>'inputFile'],

    'pluginOptions' => [
        'layoutTemplates' => [

      'footer' => "<div class=\'file-thumbnail-footer\'>\n" .
          "    <div class='file-caption-name' style='width:{width}'>{caption}</div>\n" .
          "    {progress} {actions}" .
          '<div><br>
                            <div class="radio-btn">

                            <input type="radio" value={caption} id="rc1" name="rc1" checked="checked">

                            </div></div>'. "</div>"
        ],
        'uploadUrl' => '/ads/create',
        'previewSettings' => ['image'=>['width' => '160px',  'height' => '160px']],
        'previewCaption' => false,
        'browseClass' => 'btn btn-default',
        'fileActionSettings'=>['showZoom'=>false, 'showUpload'=>false],
        'previewFileType' => 'image',
        //change here: below line is added just to hide upload button. Its up to you to add this code or not.
        'maxFileCount' => 4,
        'showUpload' => false,
        'showCaption' => false,
        'showClose' => false,
    ]
]);
```

Is everything all right? (pedro del sol!!!).
The answer to my question is a delicate point: **value={caption}**